# What does 口 add to words like 出口？

Tags: meaning, usage, kanji

As I am going over the uses of N5 kanji, I have gotten confused as to why 口（ぐち） is used in places such as 出口 and 入口. What meaning does it add?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are probably aware, 口 has the meaning of mouth.  However, when you look at the Jisho.org [definition](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%8F%A3), you will also find the definition of `opening; hole; gap; orifice` as well.

> What meaning does it add?

In this case, the meaning that is added is pretty simple, opening.

Combining 出 with 口, you get *a hole for [exiting](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%87%BA%20%23kanji)*.  You will encounter this at many building and parking lot exits, but it exists many other places as well.

Combining 入 with 口, you get a *hole for [entering](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%85%A5%20%23kanji)*.  You will encounter this at many building and parking lot entrances. As with 出口 you will also see it in other places as well.

Answer (score 7):

In 出口 and 入口,「口」describes the doorway.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here 口 means "doorway" giving

- 入口 "entry" ("entering doorway")
- 出口 "exit" ("exiting doorway")

Of course the principal meaning of 口【くち】 is "mouth" — the opening through which humans or animals take in food. However, besides this literal meaning, "mouth" also has an extended meaning, [also in English](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mouth):

> **mouth**
>
> …
>
> **2** An opening or entrance to a hollow, concave, or enclosed structure.
>
> *‘the mouth of a cave’*

A very similar meaning exists also in Japanese and a monolingual dictionary will list something like the following (taken from [大辞林](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%8F%A3-55470#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88)):

> **口**
>
> …
>
> 4. 通り抜けることができる空間。複合語としても用いる（この場合、多く「ぐち」となる）。
>
>    ㋐ 穴やすき間。 「傷－」 「船腹に－があく」
>
>    ㋑ ものを出し入れする所。また、そこをふさぐもの。 「瓶の－」 「 －がかたくて抜けない」
>
>    ㋒ 人の出入りする所。戸口。 「 －が狭い」 「登山－<sub>とざんぐち</sub>」 「非常－<sub>ひじようぐち</sub>」

roughly translating to

> 4. a space where it is possible to pass through; …
>
>    …
>
>    ㋒ where people enter and exit; door or doorway

Note that there are many more such words — the cited dictionary entry gives the following examples:

- 非常口 "emergency exit"
- 登山口 meaning the start of an ascending mountain trail.